# return statement returning before finishing the task

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Hi i am using this kill function in my application, here I am calling kill function inside a for loop each time it will return d for each iteration

but some times I am getting d value before it is completion of d.done() and after returning d it is calling d.done()
could any body please suggest me which concept i have to use here

```
kill: function() {
    var t = this
    ,   url = "My URL"//App.Data.url('user', p.get('id'), 'dissociate_tag', id)
    ,   d = _.http.del(url);

    d.done(function() {
        t.resetTile();
        t.set('killed', true);
    });

    return d;
}
```

Comment: Looks like the everyday AJAX question, see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call

Comment: Not related to your underlying problem, but `that` is undefined.

Comment: that is defined as t only in different scope

Answer (score 0):

you give `done` a callback method, which is called when it's finished, d will likely always be returned before the method passed into `done` is called.

The trick is to have the code that calls `kill` wait on d to complete (if it's important that it's finished before it continues)